# Using exec() always loading PHP

Tags: php

The Bot can run, but my problem is the page always loading..

The page will finish loading, if I Close the bot from game

```
function StartGhost($bot) {
    $ini = new INI('ghost.ini');
    $pid = $ini->data["$bot"]['pid'];
    $start_time = $ini->data["$bot"]['start_time'];

    if($pid !== false && $pid != 0) {
        return "Error: the bot is already online.";
    }


    $command = "cd /home/bot/" . $bot . "/ && nohup ./ghost++ > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!";
    $pid2 = exec($command);

    $ini->data["$bot"]['pid'] = $pid2;
    $ini->data["$bot"]['start_time'] = time();
    $ini->data["$bot"]['last_time'] = $start_time;
    $ini->write();

    return true;
}


if(isset($_GET['start']) && !isset($_GET['restart']) && !isset($_GET['stop'])) {
    echo StartGhost("bot-viva");    
}
```

the trigger code :

```
<a href="?start=bot-viva"><button>START</button></a>
```

thanks

Comment: What kind of mechanism do you use to dispatch the PHP process from the Webserver? (Like `pcntl_fork();`) PHP will wait for `exec`, it won't close anything until it has finished.

Comment: When you run the exact same command from console, does the bot dispatch from the shell and run in background?

Comment: could u give the example with pcntl_fork(); ? im newbie in PHP

Comment: @DanFromGermany if im use that command from Putty, it's run in the background..

Comment: Example is here how to start a child process: http://http://php.net/pcntl_fork